# javax.jms.ObjectMessage.getObject() throwing javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker

Tags: java, serialization, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to read the object message in Jms queue which I have set as an Integer object. I'm able to view the integer value in the Message Details of the message through browser at http://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp.

When I try to get the message details via `objectMessage.getObject()` I get the below error.

`javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class java.lang.Integer! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:208)`

I even tried adding `-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*` as VM argument even though `java.lang` anyways is included. Made no difference.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding the options on the client side or server side?

Comment: Have added the options on the client side.